# Serialize from and deserialize into different object property from same JSON property

Tags: c#, json.net

I'd like to serialize a property from a class into a json property, and when deserializing back, i'd like to read it to a different property.

Cannot figure out how to achieve this in json.net

**Minimal example:**

Backend converts a specially formatted json property into a numeric timestamp (firebase systemtimestamp).

I want to use the same abstract base class for both serialization and deserialization.

- When serializing, i need to generate a "timestamp" json property with special values.
- When deserializing, incoming json contains a number in "timestamp" property. I obviously need this to be read into a different class property.

Class:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public abstract class ItemBase
{
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    private TimestampModel WriteTimestamp => TimestampModelInstance;

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    private long ReadTimestamp { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp => DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ReadTimestamp).LocalDateTime;
}
```

I would need to somehow mark `WriteTimestamp` as "serialize only", and `ReadTimestamp`as "deserialize only"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this useful, I resolved the issue with a custom `JsonConverter`.

This way I have only one class property that has the type of the read value (long), that always serializes into `TimestampModelInstance` (the special firebase structure) regardless of the actual value

Converter:

```
public class TimestampConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(TimestampModel);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject.FromObject(TimestampModelInstance).WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

In Class:

```
[JsonProperty("timestamp")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(TimestampConverter))]
private long NumericTimestamp { get; set; }

public DateTime Timestamp => 
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(NumericTimestamp).LocalDateTime;
```